# Convert class 'pandas.indexes.numeric.Int64Index' to numpy

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe

I am isolating some row ids from a Pandas dataframe, like this:

```
data = df.loc[df.cell == id]
rows = df.index

print(type(rows))
< class 'pandas.indexes.numeric.Int64Index'>
```

I want to convert rows to a numpy array so I can save it to a mat file using sio.savemat. This is returning an error though:

```
row_mat = rows.as_matrix()
AttributeError: 'Int64Index' object has no attribute 'as_matrix'
```

What is the correct way, please? Thanks

Answer (score 53, accepted):

try `rows = df.index.values` instead

Comment: I think the OP wanted `df.loc[df.cell == id].index.values`.  If they confirm, you can update your answer.